# Windows Forms application does not always fire activate event when form is first displayed.

Tags: .net, forms, events

I do not want to spend much more time on this issue but if you are interested in reading about it and know the answer please respond. Thanks in advance.

I have a Windows Form application that starts another Windows Form application in minimized mode with ShowInTaskbar set to False. The first application has a Show button that displays the other application using the following methods.

```
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal)
        SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle)
```

I am using the Activate Event in the second application to refresh its form when activated. The problem is that, more often than not, the activate event does not fire when the form is activated. The hidden form is displayed and is activate but the activate event handler is not called. The first application is an MDI application but I do not see how that would be a factor.

There is a button on the second form to hide it. This button simply calls the form's Hide method and does not minimize the form. The next time the Show button is pressed on the first application, the activate event is fired for the second application. Setting ShowInTask bar to True for the second application does not help. Minimizing instead of hiding the window does not prevent the Activate event from being fired the second time the application is activated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because the [Activate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) is for visible Windows.  From the MSDN documentation (my emphasis):

> Activating a form brings it to the front if this is the active
>   application, or it flashes the window caption if this is not the
>   active application. **The form must be visible for this method to have
>   any effect.** To determine the active form in an application, use the
>   ActiveForm property or the ActiveMdiChild property if your forms are
>   in a Multiple-document interface (MDI) application.

As for an alternative, the first application could send a key combination to the second application to trigger the content refresh.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I suspected but the ShowWindow method makes the form visible and the SetForegroundWindow makes it active. Subsequent calls to these two methods fires the Activate event every time. It's just the first time that it only fires sometimes.

Comment: Also, the second application's window is shown and is active.

Comment: And, I have code in the FormShown event handler that I know is being called when the application starts up.

Comment: @RonCarter _"It's just the first time that [the OnActivate event] only fires sometimes."_ - hmm, that is strange. Glad to see [you've found a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12165968/5662), albeit by having to call `ShowWindow()` 3 times in succession!

Comment: It kind of sucks. I have to start the application with the Window minimized so that it isn't displayed when started. The application hides itself when started so it does not show up in the task list (My main application may start up to 30 copies of this application. Don't ask why). Apparently, the VisibleChanged event doesn't fire going from a minimized window to a normal window--even if the window was hidden and is now shown. So, I have to hide the window and then show it again to get the event to fire. I am going to play around with it a bit more to see if I can get the Active event to fire.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what is causing the issue but I was able to get around it by using the following code and switching to the VisibleChanged event instead of the form Activated event.

```
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal)
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Hide)
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal)
        SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle)
```

Note that the VisibleChanged event fires only once for the code above.

Comment: This also works:If IsIconic(WindowHandle) Then ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal) ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Hide) End If ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal) SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am giving up on trying to figure out why the form's Activated event handler does not fire reliably the first time a minimized, hidden, window is displayed and made active. I tried every combination of the ShowWindow commands I could think of. I even tried introducing timers and sleeps in case it was a timing issue. It is possible that the Activated event does not fire reliably any time a minimized window is shown and its not firing may have nothing to do with the fact that the window was hidden. I have not tested these cases.

The following code is the only code I could get to work every time using the VisibleChanged event instead of the Activate event.

```
        If IsIconic(WindowHandle) Then
            ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal)
            ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Hide)
        End If
        ShowWindow(WindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal)
        SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle)
```